# Batch file: Finding IP and opening a program

Tags: batch-file, ip-address

Alright, I'm a bit of a noob when it comes to batch files, so please be gentle :)

I'm writing a batch file that restarts programs. One of the programs should only be opened if the computer has a certain IP address. So the line I'm stuck on, would have to get the IP of the machine (They are set to static IPs) and if it has the right IP, it would open the program. If it doesn't have the right IP, to move on to the next command. I've did a lot of searching around and can't find anything I've been able to get to work.

So this line should: 1. search for the IP 2. If the IP of the machine (for argument sake) is 192.168.1.5 then it should run a certain program. 3. If the IP isn't 192.168.1.5, it will continue on to the next line which closes another program. Any help would be much appreciated! Thank you!

***Edit***

```
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
taskkill /f /im "program1.exe"
for /f "tokens=2 delims=:" %%a in ('ipconfig ^| find "IPv4 Address"') do (
set ip=%%a
set ip=!ip: =!
goto :BREAK
)
:BREAK
if %ip%==192.168.165.82 (
C:\Folder\Folder\Folder\program1.exe
) else (
taskkill /f /im "Pro gram 2.exe"
)
start "" "C:\Program Files\folder\Pro gram 2.exe"
taskkill /f /im "program3.exe"
if exist "C:\Program Files\folder\program3.exe" start "" "C:\Program Files\folder\program3.exe"
```

Comment: No shortage of results. http://www.bing.com/search?q=batch+file+find+IP

Comment: Bear in mind that machines can have multiple IP addresses (for example if they have multiple network cards).

Comment: http://superuser.com/questions/230233/how-to-get-lan-ip-to-a-variable-in-a-windows-batch-file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
for /f "tokens=2 delims=:" %%a in ('ipconfig ^| find "IPv4 Address"') do (
set ip=%%a
set ip=!ip: =!
goto :BREAK
)
:BREAK
if %ip%==192.168.1.5 (
yourprogram.exe
) else (
taskkill /im anotherprogram.exe /f
)
```

This will take the first adapters IP, if you have more than one, you will need to filter the one you want out.

To by hostname you can use something like this

```
for /f "tokens=*" %%a in ('hostname') do if "%%a"=="t2" runprogram.exe
```

Comment: I gave that a shot along with rest of my code and doesn't seem to do anything. I made sure the IP was the IP of the machine so it would work.

Comment: setlocal enabledelayedexpansion  
for /f "tokens=2 delims=:" %%a in ('ipconfig ^| find "IPv4   Address"') do (  
set ip=%%a  
set ip=!ip: =!  
goto :BREAK  
)  
:BREAK  
if %ip%==192.168.165.82 (  
C:\Folder\Folder\Folder\program1.exe  
) else (  
taskkill /f /im "Pro gram 2.exe"  
)
start "" "C:\Program Files\folder\Pro gram 2.exe"

taskkill /f /im "program3.exe"

If exist "C:\Program Files\folder\program3.exe" start "" "C:\Program Files\folder\program3.exe"

Comment: Sorry, I don't k now how to organize it on here.

Comment: I have put it into your question :) I can't see any problems with it. Does it give you any errors?

Comment: I made one mistake. At the top, it would kill program 1 first, then open it based on IP address

Comment: That usually means a syntax error, try opening a cmd prompt and drag in the batch file and run it so you can see what happened when it ran.

Comment: Here is what I get when I do that:

C:\Documents and Settings\user>"C:\Documents and Settings\user\D
esktop\Restartapps.bat"

C:\Documents and Settings\user>setlocal enabledelayedexpansion

C:\Documents and Settings\user>for /F "tokens=2 delims=:" %a in ('ipconf
ig | find "IPv4 Address"') do (
set ip=%a
 set ip=!ip: =!
 goto :BREAK
)
( was unexpected at this time.
C:\Documents and Settings\user>if ==192.168.165.82 (

Comment: I copied and pasted the code currently in your question and all I got were errors about the files not existing which is expected, but everything else worked fine. Is the code in your question the same as the code you are running when you get this error?

Comment: I just did the same thing, of course replacing the files with the right names, and it just flashes. None of the programs open or close. Nothing happens. I'm using XP Pro if that makes a difference.

Comment: Ok, I just tried it again. Program 1 closes and opens up now. But it stops when trying to close program 2. Program 2 is indeed open.

Comment: @user2022089 Yeah XP does make a difference, it will show up as `IP Address` rather than `IPv4 Address` as @Kevin pointed out. Just change that in the find string and see if that works.

Comment: Alright, so I've run into a new problem. This script will be going on windows XP and windows 7 computers. For the sake of not complicating things, I'd like to have one file for both OS. 

So I was thinking in going into a bit of a different direction. Instead of IP address, have it look for the computer name. In this case have it look for the host name t2, then run the program if it is t2. The problem I see is that some computers have a capital T and come have a lowercase t. I'm not sure how to go about coding that.

Comment: You can use the command `hostname` to get the computername as it is spelt, rather than `%computername%` which will put it all in capitals.

Comment: I have updated my answer with an example which should hopefully help you.

Comment: That's working really well! The only issue is that the computer name is still case sensitive. In this case, the computer name is T2. If I put in "T2", it runs it. But if I put in "t2", it doesn't.

Comment: I believe I just got it. I put a /I switch after the if command. Going to test this out on a few more machines. Thank you so much for your help and patience!

Comment: Ok, this works perfectly on a computer other than t2. On a t2 computer, after it loads the program based on the computer name, the command prompt stays open. I know it's supposed to close automatically. Is there a way to force it to close?

Comment: Great, glad it half works at least :) You can try using `exit >nul` to force it to close, or maybe even `taskkill /im cmd.exe /f` to make it close itself. Generally you shouldn't have to do that though, if it doesn't close on it's own then it's probably stuck on a command, which means it won't get to these ones either even if you put them in.

Comment: You're right. It gets stuck on:
for /f "tokens=*" %%a in ('hostname') do if /I "%%a"=="t2" 
C:\folder\folder\folder\program.exe

Comment: What happens if you run that single command straight from a cmd prompt? Remember use only 1 `%` for `%%a`.

Comment: Running the command by itself with %a instead of %%a opens the program just fine and the command prompt goes away.

Comment: If I run it in the command prompt I get an error saying %%a was unexpected at this time.

Comment: After doing some research, I got it to close. I added start "" in front of the program. I believe I'm good to go now. Thank you very much!

Comment: Sorry, haven't had time to reply. Glad to hear to got it sorted, no problem :)

Answer (score 0):

Please let us know what version of Windows you are running. I am on an XP machine and if I do an `IPCONFIG` the results are IP Address and not IPv4.

I know that if I run the same command on a windows 7 machine I have to filter the results by IPv4, but this won't work on Windows XP.

That being said, if you are running on an XP machine then you are filtering for IPv4, which doesn't exist, therefore your IP variable will never be set to anything and your code will not run.

Please report back what OS version you are running. Change your filter accordingly. You can just go to the command line and type `IPCONFIG` and see what the output is like.

Fow Windows XP change the for loop to the below:

```
for /f "tokens=2 delims=:" %%a in ('ipconfig ^| find "IP Address"') do...
```

When I do this on my PC is get the desired IP Address set as a variable.